# How to do multiline input in phpsh?

Tags: phpsh

Can I something like:

```
php>multline start; 
.... $a =<<< EOF 
.... hello hi how are you this is phpSH 
.... hello there its test line 
.... EOF; 
.... multiline end;
```

in phpsh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take an example, if multiline statement:

1. Type: if (condition) {
2. Just hit Enter
3. ...  and write what you want.
4. } Close the multiline statement. And hit Enter to execute it.

You can further cancel writing by hitting ctrl + c.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just like this:

```
php> $test = "
 ... hello hi how are you this is phpSH
 ... hello there its test line
 ... "
    <the_empty_result>
php>
php> echo $test

hello hi how are you this is phpSH
hello there its test line

php>
php> =$test
"\nhello hi how are you this is phpSH\nhello there its test line\n"
```

or

```
php> $test = "hello hi how are you this is phpSH
 ... hello there its test line"
    <the_empty_result>
php>
php> echo $test
hello hi how are you this is phpSH
hello there its test line
php>
php> =$test
"hello hi how are you this is phpSH\nhello there its test line"
```

Of course, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to create the above multiline input.